# How to use python-can send a tx message(can message)

Tags: python-can

```
import can
bus = can.Bus(interface='vector',
              app_name='CANoe',
              channel=[0],
              receive_own_messages=True)

message = can.Message(arbitration_id=123,data=[0x11, 0x22, 0x33])
print("send msg:")
print(message)
bus.send(message, timeout=0.2)`enter code here`

print("received msg:")
print(bus.recv())
bus.shutdown()
```

output:
send msg:
Timestamp:        0.000000    ID: 0000007b    X Rx                DL:  3    11 22 33
received msg:
Timestamp: 1647263400.094132        ID: 0000    S Rx E              DL:  0